# How to show an alert whenever an Item is selected in SharePoint drop down choice menu Field in a SharePoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, choice-field

I am having a SharePoint list which has a drop down menu field.

I want to show an alert as soon as a user selects any item from the drop down menu.

Comment: why? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to insert the selected value in the drop down to another list. But it should be added as soon as any item is selected in the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code at script editor that show an alert message when an item selected from the choice field at your form.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("select[title='choice column name']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='choice column name']").val() != "the selected value")
{
alert("qassas");
}

});
});

</script>
```

For step by step guide with images [check Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)